# impossible to create a new column python

Tags: python, pandas

I try to create a column "TYRES" which contain the value "Y" if all 3 columns LIMITED_SUMMER_TYRES, LIMITED_WINTER_TYRES  and  LIMITED_MIXED_TYRES contains "Y" value.
I try with this belowed code but I got this error :

> At line 20: <type 'exceptions.ValueError'>: The truth value of a
> Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or
> a.all().

Any idea please to resolve this problem? thanks

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


# Read recipe inputs
lease_OUT_TYRES = dataiku.Dataset("LEASE_OUT_TYRES")
lease_OUT_TYRES_df = lease_OUT_TYRES.get_dataframe()


# Compute recipe outputs from inputs
# TODO: Replace this part by your actual code that computes the output, as a Pandas dataframe
# NB: DSS also supports other kinds of APIs for reading and writing data. Please see doc.




# create a list of our conditions
conditions = [
    (lease_OUT_TYRES_df['LIMITED_SUMMER_TYRES'] == 'y'  and lease_OUT_TYRES_df['LIMITED_WINTER_TYRES'] == 'y' and lease_OUT_TYRES_df['LIMITED_MIXED_TYRES'] == 'y' )
    
    ]

# create a list of the values we want to assign for each condition
values = ['Y']

# create a new column and use np.select to assign values to it using our lists as arguments
lease_OUT_TYRES_df['TYRES'] = np.select(conditions, values)



tyre_df = lease_OUT_TYRES_df # For this sample code, simply copy input to output


# Write recipe outputs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use Python's regular `and` to compare columns, because it will try to compare the entire column objects, instead of each element inside each column. You need to use the *bitwise and* (`&`) for this:

```
result = (
    (lease_OUT_TYRES_df['LIMITED_SUMMER_TYRES'] == 'y') & 
    (lease_OUT_TYRES_df['LIMITED_WINTER_TYRES'] == 'y') & 
    (lease_OUT_TYRES_df['LIMITED_MIXED_TYRES'] == 'y')
)
lease_OUT_TYRES_df['TYRES'] = result.map({True: 'y', False: 'n'})
```

Comment: Okay thank you for this explanation. It works!